# Cannot Create Directories On Ubuntu With Bash Shell Script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, vagrant

I'm trying to run this bash shell script to create directories for vim syntax highlighting on Ubuntu 13.04 (via Vagrant 1.4.1 on Windows 7).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

basevim="$HOME/.vim"
ftdetect="${basevim}/ftdetect"
indent="${basevim}/indent"
syntax="${basevim}/syntax"

echo "Setting up VIM for syntax highlighting"
#Create directories for vim syntax highlighting
if [ ! -d "$basevim" ]; then
    echo "Adding VIM syntax highlighting dirs"
    mkdir "$basevim"
    mkdir "$ftdetect"
    mkdir "$indent"
    mkdir "$syntax"
else
   if [ ! -d "$ftdetect" ]; then    
    mkdir "$ftdetect"
   fi
   if [ ! -d "$indent" ]; then
    mkdir "$indent"
   fi
   if [ ! -d "$syntax" ]; then
    mkdir "$syntax"
   fi   
fi
```

This is executing as a provision.sh script for Vagrant so as far as I know it should run as root. I can see the echo'd message so it's taking the first branch.  But for the life of me I can't seem to get this to work; no complaints but the directories don't get created.  If I set those variables on an interactive prompt, I need to do `sudo mkdir ftdetect` (etc.) to get the directories created. Strangely I don't need to sudo to get the .vim directory created--at least that's what I recall.

I tried

```
if [ ! -d "${basevim}" ]; then
```

but that didn't do anything. I also tried

```
basevim="{$HOME}/.vim"
```

--also no dice. Any thoughts of what I may be missing?  As I say, as far as I know it shouldn't be necessary to sudo on a provisioning script on Vagrant. I can tell the script is getting run because those echo'd messages are getting output.

Comment: can you add a "whoami" somewhere near the top of the script to get the current user name printed to the log? That way you could verify that it runs as root.

Comment: The `-p` switch to `mkdir` obviates the need to check for the existence of a directory before creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script could be replaced by

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/.vim"/{ftdetect,indent,syntax}
```

As for the directories not appearing... Where are you looking for them?

Running this as root would create them in root's home directory, `/root/`, and not in the user's home directory `/home/username`. When in doubt, use absolute path names (and `chown` as needed afterwards).